# Destination directory contents after selecting a dir using Browse

Tags: install4j

testing our install4j-Installer I'm a little confused about the behavior of the Installation location screen:

- When this screen is displayed, in field Destination directory the
  directory of the last installation is suggested (e.g. c:\xx\a).
- Now I use the "Browse" button to select another directory (e.g.
  c:\xx\b).
- After OK in the "Select Directory" dialog I'll see in field
  Destination directory c:\xx\b\a instead of c:\xx\b.

Is this a bug? Did I configure something wrong? Thanks in advance!

Best regards!

Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the "Installation location" screen, deselect "Suggest application directory" to disable this behavior.